# Adding textbox at dynamic positions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox, position

I want to add few text boxes at dynamic position in a form.

Say something like this [image]

I have JavaScript like this:

```
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement('<input type="checkbox" name="chk">');
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement('<INPUT type="text" name="SubpartID"/>');
        cell4.appendChild(element4);

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element5 = document.createElement('<INPUT type="text" name="Quantity" value="1" />');
        cell5.appendChild(element5);

    }
```

but problem with this script is, When I click "Add Subpart Input Row" button, I am able to see a new row added but only with check box in that.

I guess `cell4.appendChild(element4);` and `cell5.appendChild(element5);` does not work.

So the output looks like this,

[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: If you're on Firefox with Firebug or on Google Chrome, can you confirm that there are no errors when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using `document.createElement` the wrong way. You need to do it like this:

```
var element5 = document.createElement('input');
    element5.type = 'text';
    element5.name = 'Quantity';
    element5.value = 1;
cell5.appendChild(element5);
```

Should be the same for the rest except with different attributes and value.

Comment: I figured this out. I should had dummy child at row.
'row.insertCell(1);' and 'row.insertCell(2);'